# Why 2 queries are executed instead of one?

Tags: mysql, django

I have following piece of code:

```
def detail(request, popular_id):
   try:
      popular = Popular.objects.get(pk = popular_id)
      share = Share.objects.get(isin = popular.isin) #LINE 1
      chart_data_json = share.get_chart_data_json()
   except Popular.DoesNotExist:
      raise Http404
   return render(request, 'popular/detail.html', {'popular': popular, 'chart_data': chart_data_json})
```

In LINE 1 I noticed using debug-toolbar that there are two queries get executed:

```
SELECT `share_share`.`id`, `share_share`.`symbol`, `share_share`.`isin`, `share_share`.`name`, `share_share`.`market`, `share_share`.`updated` FROM `share_share` WHERE `share_share`.`id` = 1
```

and

```
SELECT `share_share`.`id`, `share_share`.`symbol`, `share_share`.`isin`, `share_share`.`name`, `share_share`.`market`, `share_share`.`updated` FROM `share_share` WHERE `share_share`.`isin` = 'US5949181045'
```

I cannot understand why we need the first query and how to avoid it?

EDIT:

Model definition of share:

```
class Share(models.Model):
   symbol = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
   isin = models.CharField(max_length = 12)
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
   market = models.CharField(max_length = 64)
   updated = models.BooleanField(default = False)

   def get_chart_data_json(self):
      quote_model = create_quote_model(str(self.isin))
      data = quote_model.objects.values('date', 'adj_close', 'volume')
      chart_data = []
      for d in data.iterator():
         chart_data.append({'date': d['date'].isoformat(), 'value': d['adj_close'], 'volume': d['volume']})
      chart_data_json = json.dumps(chart_data)
      return chart_data_json

   def __unicode__(self):
      return self.isin
```

Model definition of popular:

```
class Popular(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
   text = models.CharField(max_length = 1024)
   isin = models.ForeignKey(Share)

   def __unicode__(self):
      return self.title
```

Comment: Can you provide model definitions for Popular and Share?

Comment: Added model definitions to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First query is evaluated when you access foreign key isin from popular object:

   share = Share.objects.get(isin = **popular.isin**)
2. Second query gets Share object:

   share = **Share.objects.get**(isin = popular.isin)

If you want just one query at #LINE 1 you should replace it with:

```
share = popular.isin #LINE 1
```